# Initialise Generic List whilst providing multiple collections? c#

Tags: c#, generics, collections, generic-list

```
var a = new []{"a"};
var b = new []{"b"};
var c = new []{"c"};
```

Is it possible to declare / initialise a generic list, providing the three collections above in one line?

```
var l = new List<string>(a); //fine for one
var l2 = new List<string>(new[] { a, b, c }.SelectMany(x => x)); //this will work but its horrible!
```

Comment: I think you have the simplest of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
var list = a.Concat(b).Concat(c).ToList();
```